# php - get xpath from phpquery object

Tags: php, dom, xpath

i'm using [PHPquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) to parse HTML file
for example i have this file

```
<div id="header" class="clearit" role="banner">
        <div id="headerWrapper">
            <ul id="primaryNav" role="navigation">
                <li id="musicNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="/music" class="nav-link">Music</a>
                </li>
                <li id="listenNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="/listen" class="nav-link">Radio</a>
                </li>
                <li id="eventsNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="/events" class="nav-link">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li id="chartsNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="/charts" class="nav-link">Charts</a>
                </li>
                <li id="communityNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="/community" class="nav-link">Community</a>
                </li>
                <li id="originalsNav" class="navItem">
                    <a href="http://originals.last.fm" class="nav-link">Originals</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
</div>
```

the query :

```
$link=pq(".nav-link")->eq(0);
$xpath=$link->xpath;
```

now xpath is an [DOMXpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) object and i want to get the Xpath for this object like :

```
$result="//html//body//div//div//ul//li[0]//a[0]";
```

if this not possible in PHPquery how can i get it in PHP?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to get the XPath expression?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Getting XPath of a DOMNode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643533/php-getting-xpath-of-a-domnode)

Comment: I'm traversing the DOM tree using .children() function after several moves in the tree i want the path to the current node so i think if i get the XPath for it will be enough.

Comment: @FarokOjil That does not answer *why* you want the path. What are you planning to do with it?

Comment: i'm trying to get content from web pages like i want to save the xpath of the tag that holds the price on amazon so i can get it in future.

Comment: @Farok Then I'd recommend writing the XPath by hand. Something like `//li[@id='musicNav']/a` is a lot more stable than any XPath you could generate automatically. They only need to change their HTML structure slightly and you generated XPath will fail.

Comment: I know this question is kind of outdated but I had the same problem and found the function `getNodeXpath` in the phpQuery Class, which will give this result. However, this method has a protected access, so could maybe extend it.